# SQLitePersistent objects only loading NSNumber fields, everything else left null

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa, sqlite

I've used SQLitePersistentObjects for a lot of different iPhone projects and haven't yet encountered this issue. I'm not sure if it's a bug or merely an issue on my part.

I have a model with quite a few fields in it. Here are the fields enumerated as they exist in the sqlite database:

```
SELECT pk,sender_i_d,read,target,web_u_r_l,sender_type,client_type,thread_i_d,replied_to_i_d,direct_to_i_d,message_i_d,group_i_d,u_r_l,target_i_d,created_at,network_p_k,body_parsed,message_type,attachment_p_ks,body_plain FROM message
```

When I create the models, all fields are properly serialized to disk. The models work fine as long as they exist in memory. However, when I re-launch the application, all fields are not loaded into the model, anything with a TEXT sqlite field is left `null`.

If I use the sqlite3 console I can successfully select data from the models, the data is all there.

Has anyone else had this issue with SQLitePersistentObjects, or sqlite3? Am I using some bizarre reserved word in sqlite3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For any SQLitePersistentObject users that may happen upon this in the future, here is a lesson :

Don't use properties that start with a capital letter! SQLitePersistentObjects will probably puke!